# CSS div's containing classes

Tags: html, css

So my logic of Div ID's and Classes must be WAY off.

Heres whats going on:

[image]

As you can see the blocks which say PS don't align center with the slider (Which is inside a container.

Here is my css:

```
/*Front Page Buttons */

#frontpage-Button-Cont {

    height: 350px;

}

.button-cont {
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
}

.thumbnail {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 5em;
    background: #1f4e9b;
    width: 175px;
    height: 135px;
    text-align: center;

}
.pheader {
    color: #DC143C;
    min-width: 175px;
    text-align: center;


}
.paragraph {
    text-align: center;
}

#Align-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="frontpage-Button-Cont">
    <div id="Align-content">
        <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                PS
            </div>

            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="pheader">
                    HEADER
                </div>

                <p>dadaasdasdadadad
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                PS
            </div>

            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="pheader">
                    HEADER
                </div>

                <p>dadaasdasdadadad
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                PS
            </div>

            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="pheader">
                    HEADER
                </div>

                <p>dadaasdasdadadad
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                PS
            </div>

            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="pheader">
                    HEADER
                </div>

                <p>dadaasdasdadadad
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My theory is that I'm using classes incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: So are you trying to align all the buttons in the centre of the page?

Comment: Also try applying text-align: center to #Align-content

Comment: In my opinion, you use classes on divs everywhere, while you should target the proper elements. Here is a fiddle with a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/7u32f/2/

Comment: None of your `p` elements are closed, I'd start there. Try cleaning up your code and properly nesting your html, and reposting the resulting code here. It will help people troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Hey Shawn, Not closing p elements is a trait of mine! I'l go back and change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Add this to your CSS

```
#frontpage-Button-Cont {
  width:100%;
}

#Align-content {
  display:table;
}
```

With this your `margin:o auto` can work

View This Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/VGPeW/**

Comment: u're welcome you're using very well the classes all you miss was a little property for your containers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the containing div (in this case `frontpage-Button-Cont`) is the same width as your slider above it. Then add the property `text-align:center` to the container. That *should* fix your issue.

Comment: Sadly, this option didn't work for me. Thanks for the effort but Danko successfully answered it :)